# Python: How to separate a String with a List

Tags: python, list, substring

If let's say I know the type of currencies. How do I separate the following strings?
Units = ["Dollar", "Yuan", "Rupee", "USDT"]

For Example:

```
TwoDollar
FiveYuan
EightRupee
TwentyUSDT
```

Result:

```
Two
Five
Eight
Twenty

Dollar
Yuan
Rupee
USDT
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well it is very basic question of python you must research first but here is the answer for your help in the easiest way possible if you want explaination for it I will help you.

```
values = ['TwoDollar',
'FiveYuan',
'EightRupee',
'TwentyUSDT']

currencies = ['Dollar','Yuan','Rupee','USDT']

for value in values:
    for currency in currencies:
        if currency in value:
            print(value[: value.index(currency,0)])
            print(value[ value.index(currency,0) :])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re` module:

```py
import re

s = ["TwoDollar", "FiveYuan", "EightRupee", "TwentyUSDT"]
units = ["Dollar", "Yuan", "Rupee", "USDT"]

r = re.compile("(.*?)(" + "|".join(map(re.escape, units)) + ")")

amounts, u = [], []
for word in s:
    m = r.search(word)
    if m:
        amounts.append(m.group(1))
        u.append(m.group(2))

print(*amounts, sep="\n")
print()
print(*u, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
Two
Five
Eight
Twenty

Dollar
Yuan
Rupee
USDT
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one-liner:

```
import re

uns = ["Dollar", "Yuan", "Rupee", "USDT"]
lst = ["TwoDollar", "FiveYuan", "EightRupee", "TwentyUSDT"]

amounts, units = map(list, 
                     zip(*(re.match(f'^(.*)({u})$', s).groups() 
                           for u, s in zip(uns, lst))))
```

Result:

```
>>> amounts
['Two', 'Five', 'Eight', 'Twenty']
>>> units
['Dollar', 'Yuan', 'Rupee', 'USDT']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way for you is using the "split" function,

```
mySting = "twentytwodollar"
print(myString.split("dollar"))
```

```
money = "Yuan"
mySting = "FiveYuan"
print(myString.split(money))
```

[the complete datasheet](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Comment: And what about `FiveYuan`?

Comment: just do the same with myString.split("Yuan"), the string passed can be a variable like so :   

money = "Yuan"      
myString = "FiveYuan"      
print(mySting.split(money))

Comment: What if this is just an example and you don't know all the possible options?

Comment: This is a poor solution. It will work inside a loop but is not very nice.

Comment: you pass your function a variable, see my second exemple on the main answer

Comment: @DanielArgüelles I know it is not nice, but beginners usually don't understand the regex functions you give them... using this he will. That's why I told it was the "easiest" solution, not prettiest or fastest though

Answer (score 0):

For **Python3.9**

```
units = ["Dollar", "Yuan", "Rupee", "USDT"]
values = ["TwoDollar","FiveYuan","EightRupee","TwentyUSDT"]

value_list = []
unit_list = []
for value in values:
    for unit in units:
        if unit in value:
            value_list.push(string1.removesuffix(unit))
            unit_list.push(unit)
            break

# print your value_list and unit_list
```

Read more about `removesuffix` [here](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix)

Answer (score 0):

Since  both amount and unit start all with an uppercase in your strings, you don't even need to know the type of currencies, simply try:

```
import re

values = ["TwoDollar", "FiveYuan", "EightRupee", "TwentyUSDT"]

amounts, units = [], []
for s in values:
    outputs = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+[a-z]*', s) 
    amounts.append(outputs[0])
    units.append(outputs[1])

print(*amounts, '\n', *units, sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

just for completeness here is a simple list comprehension example

```
cur = ['Dollar', 'Yuan', 'Rupee', 'USDT']

vals= ['TwoDollar', 'FiveYuan', 'EightRupee', 'TwentyUSDT']

print([a.split(x)[0] for a in vals for x in cur if len(a.split(x)) == 2])
```

output is

```
['Two', 'Five', 'Eight', 'Twenty']
```

if you wanna have the currency in the result you might wanna build a tuple as list item.

```
[(a.split(x)[0], x) for a in vals for x in cur if len(a.split(x)) == 2]
```

gets you this

```
[('Two', 'Dollar'), ('Five', 'Yuan'), ('Eight', 'Rupee'), ('Twenty', 'USDT')]
```

cheers

Markus

Comment: you can even improve the test if you do a upper() or lower() befor the split and x so it always matches even some letters are upper or lower case. for example if you are not defining the values to split